# Spring Security + Thymeleaf + HTMX -> 403 Error

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf, csrf-token, htmx

How do I suppose to use Spring Security + Thymeleaf + HTMX and not get 403?

I am relatively new in using Spring Security, especialy with thymeleaf and htmX...

So I am trying to keep features of Spring security and still be able to use htmx, but I'm getting 403.

If I disable csrf in my config, I am loosing all authentication view.

My index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "ISO-8859-1" />
      <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet" />
      <title>Logowanie</title>
      <script th:src="@{/js/scripts.js}" defer></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.7.0" integrity="sha384-EzBXYPt0/T6gxNp0nuPtLkmRpmDBbjg6WmCUZRLXBBwYYmwAUxzlSGej0ARHX0Bo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
      <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
   </head>
   <body hx-boost="true">
    <div class="center">
      <h4>Witamy w panelu klienta!</h4>
      <button id="myButton" th:onclick="hello()">Hello Button</button>
      <button id="button2" th:onClick="info()">info in console</button>
      <p id="sayHello" hx-post="/hello" hx-swap="outerHTML">ppp</p>
      <!-- <div sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')">Text visible to user.</div>
      <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">Text visible to admin.</div>
      <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
         Text visible only to authenticated users.
      </div>
      Authenticated username:
      <div sec:authentication="name"></div>
      Authenticated user roles:
      <div sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></div> -->
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```java
@Controller
public class MainView {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String mainView(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("password", "dupka");
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/panel")
    public String panelView(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("password", "dupeczka");
        return "test";
    }

    @PostMapping("/hello")
    // @PostMapping(headers = "HX-Request")
    public String furtherInfo() {
        return "fragments/invoices";
        // return "test";
    }
}
```

Config file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyGlobalSecurityConfig 
{
    
    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password("{noop}password")
        .roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("admin")
        .password("{noop}password")
        .roles("ADMIN");
    }
```

I have tried to disable csrf but I am loosing authentication view from my app -> app is acting like there is no Spring security.

I did this change to disable csrf:

```java
     @Bean
     public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
         .csrf().disable();
         return http.build();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the htmx:config request to further configure your requests.
I have following script in my main thymeleaf layout:

```
  document.body.addEventListener("htmx:configRequest", function (evt) {
    evt.detail.headers["accept"] = "text/html-partial";

    if (evt.detail.verb !== "get") {
      const csrfHeaderName = document
        .querySelector("meta[name='_csrf_header']")
        .getAttribute("content");
      evt.detail.headers[csrfHeaderName] = document
        .querySelector("meta[name='_csrf']")
        .getAttribute("content");
    }
  });
```

And the meta headers are looking like this:

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
```

So the [htmx:configRequest](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:configRequest) callback reads the expected csrf header name from the the meta data and the csrf token and manipulates the request which will be send to the server. With the if condition we only send the csrf headers with manipulating http verbs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the CSRF token in the HTMX requests. You can include it in the headers of the HTMX request:

```
<body hx-headers='{"${_csrf.headerName}": "${_csrf.token}"}'>
   ...
</body>
```

The [`hx-headers`](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-headers/) attribute is inherited in the child elements, so you can just put it on the topmost `<body>` element.

You can also put the token into a hidden form input and include it in the request with [`hx-include`](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-include/):

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
<button hx-post="/hello" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-include="[name='${_csrf.parameterName}']">Load content</button>
```

Comment: hmm, I am receiving "Uncaught DOMException: Invalid header name.", when I am adding it to the body (so it is kind of progress), Unfortunately adding a hidden input form does not seem to have any effect

Comment: What throws this error and when? You can also add it directly to the element where `hx-post` is located.

Comment: after click on trigger element: <p id="sayHello" hx-post="/hello" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-headers='{"${_csrf.headerName}": "${_csrf.token}"}'>ppp</p>             also I have tried : <p id="sayHello" hx-post="/hello" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-headers='{"${_csrf.parameterName}": "${_csrf.token}"}'>ppp</p>                          This error message occurs in a browser (no error in ide)

Comment: Could you share the rendered HTML of this line? I wonder what's the final value of `${_csrf.headerName}`.

Comment: _csrf.headerName: X-CSRF-TOKEN

_csrf.parameterName: _csrf

_csrf.token: qtaL1Q_zEU-wbNBddzqyhnUF7owuhFKR62svPCV1_rRMDPvnmeO952uVdHudDuJsEReGv0Yyw7Qetma8jl4XXRMTyYx-b56D

Comment: I have also tried it by the postman, so: 1. get request can be authenticated by 'basic authentication'. Unfortunately, the 2. post request is still retrieving the 401

Answer (score 0):

So, including headers into the body dose NOT work... atleast for me...
But writing it like:

```
<form hx-post="/stringi" hx-swap="outerHTML">
        <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <input type="submit" th:text="submit">
    </form>
```

Do work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for the adding attribute to a body part:

```
 <body hx-headers='js:{"X-CSRF-TOKEN": token}'>
```

but  first we need to extract token from thymeleaf into js, like:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    const token = /*[[${_csrf.token}]]*/ "token";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell htmx to add specific headers for each htmx-related request using the `hx-headers` attribute. If you set it on your body-element, it is applied "globally". You can construct the header as follows:

`<body hx:headers="${'&quot;' + _csrf.headerName + '&quot;: &quot;' + _csrf.token + '&quot;'}">`

Note that I am using the [htmx-spring-boot](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/htmx-spring-boot) library, which allows the `hx:someHtmxAttribute` syntax for better HTMX <-> Thymeleaf integration.